# Sequence of measurable functions with |f_n|^2<g

Tags: measurable-functions

Suppose {f_n} is a sequence of measurable functions on [0,1] such that limit(as n goes to infinity) integral over [0,1] |f_n|=0 and that there is an integrable function g on [0,1] such that 
|f_n|^2 is less than or equal to g. Prove that limit(as n goes to infinity) integral over [0,1] 
|f_n|^2=0

Comment: Maybe apply the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: Hi ! If you haven't done so yet, I would recommend you to take a close look at [this page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question), which lists some tips to ask a good question on this site. It would be great if you could edit your question accordingly.